# Usage of "yet" and "but"

Tags: word-usage

I want to convey "Something is important. But it is hard to achieve". Can I use "yet" as in the following sentence?

> It is an important yet non-trivial task.

Also, can I use "yet" to connect sentences with opposite meanings? For example,

> This book is very well-written, yet few people know about it.

Comment: Ida, welcome. You may be interested in visiting [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions), a new StackExchange proposal specifically dedicated to those who want to learn the English language. Here on EL&U your question is considered too elementary, and this may explain the presence of the negative vote you've already got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use *yet* in your first example. You need AND.
Alternatively, change the order and use *but*.

> *It is a non-trivial but important task.*

***6. used for introducing a word or idea that is surprising after what has just been mentioned***

- *They had plenty of time, yet she felt there was almost none.*
- *The novel is 800 pages long, yet it reads more quickly than many shorter books.*
- *He looks cheerful yet somehow sad at the same time.*

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/yet

---

Your second example is an example of correct usage

> *This book is very well-written, yet few people know about it.*